# MYSQL PHP Combine Multiple Rows into One Based on a Duplicate Column

Tags: php, mysql, merge, duplicates

I have an email list that has a lot of duplicate data in it and I want to merge rows that have duplicate data in a certain column..

Here is the table that I have:

```
autoid,title,lastname,firstname,middlename,prefix,
fulladdress,address1,address2,
city,state,zip,country,county,phone1,phone2,email,id, ts
```

I want to merge duplicate rows based on email and phone1.  If the contents of these are the same in two rows then I want to merge the rows and fill in any blanks and then drop the second row.  The data in the row with the lower autoid would take precedence over the row with the higher id.

If we can do this with a single mysql query would be great but if we have to use PHP that would work as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a mysql query that will merge them automatically, but PHP is definitely a solution. I'll let the mySQL gods look over this first and if not then let me know and we will get a PHP solution for you.

Comment: Ok SnareChops lets work out some PHP code that would work.

Comment: @ToddWelch, when talking to someone, put an `@` in front of his name. In this case SnareChops will have been notified in any case, as he was the only one to comment so far, but in general he might not have been. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/188688.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine multiple rows into a single one using something like

```sql
GROUP BY email, phone1
```

If you just insert this, you get any one of the combined rows. If you want values to take precedence over `NULL` fields, you would use aggregate functins like e.g. `MIN`:

```sql
SELECT MIN(title), MIN(lastname), …
FROM tableName
GROUP BY email, phone1
```

But this makes the decision about which value to take for each row separately. A query which combines rows but does so in the way you describe would be rather tricky in MySQL. You could have one query which lists all rows in order of matching columns and then descending `autoid`, using user variables to fill in the gaps. But not filling in the gaps in the non-matching rows would be hard, so one subquery for each matching pair would probably work better. Except for performance, and readability of the query, so on the whole, you're probably better off with a PHP solution.

In PHP, things should be rather easy: query the database with

```sql
ORDER BY email, phnone1, autoid ASC
```

then on the PHP side, for each row you read from the database, check whether it matches the previously read row in the two specific columns. If it does, iterate over the columns, replacing `null`s as you go. I'm not much of a PHP coder these days, so someone else might be better suited to write a code snippet for this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information MvG.  I think I will try to hammer out some PHP code with SnareChops above.

Answer (score -3):

We really don't like providing complete code solutions on StackOverflow, usually we assist you in writing your own, but I'm not sure if I could've explained all the steps without actually writing the code to figure it out myself, so here is some starter code.

**THIS IS UNTESTED RAW CODE**

First ***MAKE A COPY OF YOUR EXISTING TABLE*** until we know this code is not going to harm or drop your existing data do everything on a copy, then once it's ironed out and you've verified that it will work appropriately then apply it to the correct table.

Create a copy using:

```
CREATE TABLE EmailListCopy LIKE EmailList; 
INSERT EmailListCopy SELECT * FROM EmailList;
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

//This script will first query the table for ALL results, store them in arrays, 
//then loop through the arrays to search the table for duplicates using individual
//sql queries and then compare the results, update the entry as needed and delete the
//duplicate row. THIS CODE IS NOT OPTIMIZED!! DO NOT RUN CONTINUOUSLY!! This should be
//used for OCCASIONAL merging ONLY!! i.e. Once-a-day or once-a-week etc...
$result="";
$duplicatesFound;
//Setup arrays to hold the original query information
$autoidArray = array();
$titleArray = array();
$lastnameArray = array();
$firstnameArray = array();
$middlenameArray = array();
$prefixArray = array();
$fulladdressArray = array();
$address1Array = array();
$address2Array = array();
$cityArray = array();
$stateArray = array();
$zipArray = array();
$countryArray = array();
$countyArray = array();
$phone1Array = array();
$phone2Array = array();
$emailArray = array();
$idArray = array();
$tsArray = array();
$link=mysqli_connect($hostname,$dbname,$password,$username);
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    $result="Error connecting to database: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
    $stmt=mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT autoid,title,lastname,firstname,middlename,prefix,fulladdress,address1,address2,city,state,zip,country,county,phone1,phone2,email,id,ts FROM " . $table);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $autoid, $title, $lastname, $firstname, $middlename, $prefix, $fulladdress, $address1, $address2, $city, $state, $zip, $country, $county, $phone1, $phone2, $email, $id, $ts);
    if(mysqli_stmt_errno($stmt))
    {
        $result="Error executing SQL statement: ".mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
    }
    else
    {
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)==0)
        {
            $result="0 rows returned (Empty table)";
        }
        else 
        {
            while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
            {
                //Load results into arrays
                array_push($autoidArray, $autoid);
                array_push($titleArray, $title);
                array_push($lastnameArray, $lastname);
                array_push($firstnameArray, $firstname);
                array_push($middlenameArray, $middlename);
                array_push($prefixArray, $prefix);
                array_push($fulladdressArray, $fulladdress);
                array_push($address1Array, $address1);
                array_push($address2Array, $address2);
                array_push($cityArray, $city);
                array_push($stateArray, $state);
                array_push($zipArray, $zip);
                array_push($countryArray, $country);
                array_push($countyArray, $county);
                array_push($phone1Array, $phone1);
                array_push($phone2Array, $phone2);
                array_push($emailArray, $email);
                array_push($idArray, $id);
                array_push($tsArray, $ts);
            }
        }
        mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
    }
    for($i=0;$i<count($emailArray);$i++)
    {
        $duplicatestmt=mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT autoid,title,lastname,firstname,middlename,prefix,fulladdress,address1,address2,city,state,zip,country,county,phone1,phone2,email,id,ts FROM " . $table . " WHERE email=? OR phone1=?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($duplicatestmt, 'si', $emailArray[$i], $phone1Array[$i]);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($duplicatestmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($duplicatestmt, $autoid, $title, $lastname, $firstname, $middlename, $prefix, $fulladdress, $address1, $address2, $city, $state, $zip, $country, $county, $phone1, $phone2, $email, $id, $ts);
        if(mysqli_stmt_errno($duplicatestmt))
        {
            $result="Error executing SQL statement: ".mysqli_stmt_error($duplicatestmt);
        }
        else
        {
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($duplicatestmt);
            if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($duplicatestmt)==0)
            {
                //NO Duplicate entry found, loop again;
                echo "<p>No Dublicate Found</p>";
            }
            else 
            {
                while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($duplicatestmt))
                {
                    //Found a duplicate
                    echo "<p>Dublicate Found</p>";
                    if($autoid > $autoidArray[$i])
                    {
                        if($email=="" && $phone1=="")
                        {
                            echo "<p>Both email and phone1 are empty. Skipping...</p>";
                        else
                        {
                        $duplicatesFound++;
                        //The autoid of the duplicate just found is greater then the autoid of the
                        //one used to find the duplicate (older). Therefor update the entry and remove the
                        //duplicate
                        //
                        //This checks each of the values and if the lower autoid one is blank, then will add the
                        //value to the table in the lower autoid row
                        //NOTE:** If having any problems with the queries below try removing the single quotes -> ' <- from any "autoid=" portion of the query
                        if($titleArray[$i]==""){mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE EmailListCopy SET title='".$title."' WHERE autoid='".$autoidArray[$i]."'");}
                        if($lastnameArray[$i]==""){mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE EmailListCopy SET title='".$firstname."' WHERE autoid='".$autoidArray[$i]."'");}
                        if($firstnameArray[$i]==""){mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE EmailListCopy SET title='".$lastname."' WHERE autoid='".$autoidArray[$i]."'");}
                        if($middlenameArray[$i]==""){mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE EmailListCopy SET title='".$middlename."' WHERE autoid='".$autoidArray[$i]."'");}
                        if($prefixArray[$i]==""){mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE EmailListCopy SET title='".$prefix."' WHERE autoid='".$autoidArray[$i]."'");}
                        if($fulladdressArray[$i]==""){mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE EmailListCopy SET title='".$fulladdress."' WHERE autoid='".$autoidArray[$i]."'");}
                        if($address1Array[$i]==""){mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE EmailListCopy SET title='".$address1."' WHERE autoid='".$autoidArray[$i]."'");}
                        if($address2Array[$i]==""){mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE EmailListCopy SET title='".$address2."' WHERE autoid='".$autoidArray[$i]."'");}
                        if($cityArray[$i]==""){mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE EmailListCopy SET title='".$city."' WHERE autoid='".$autoidArray[$i]."'");}
                        if($stateArray[$i]==""){mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE EmailListCopy SET title='".$state."' WHERE autoid='".$autoidArray[$i]."'");}
                        if($zipArray[$i]==""){mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE EmailListCopy SET title='".$zip."' WHERE autoid='".$autoidArray[$i]."'");}
                        if($countryArray[$i]==""){mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE EmailListCopy SET title='".$country."' WHERE autoid='".$autoidArray[$i]."'");}
                        if($countyArray[$i]==""){mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE EmailListCopy SET title='".$county."' WHERE autoid='".$autoidArray[$i]."'");}
                        if($phone1Array[$i]==""){mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE EmailListCopy SET title='".$phone1."' WHERE autoid='".$autoidArray[$i]."'");}
                        if($phone2Array[$i]==""){mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE EmailListCopy SET title='".$phone2."' WHERE autoid='".$autoidArray[$i]."'");}
                        if($emailArray[$i]==""){mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE EmailListCopy SET title='".$email."' WHERE autoid='".$autoidArray[$i]."'");}
                        if($idArray[$i]==""){mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE EmailListCopy SET title='".$id."' WHERE autoid='".$autoidArray[$i]."'");}
                        if($tsArray[$i]==""){mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE EmailListCopy SET title='".$ts."' WHERE autoid='".$autoidArray[$i]."'");}

                        //Now that it has been updated, delete the duplicate entry
                        mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM EmailListCopy WHERE autoid='".$autoid."'");
                        echo "<p>Duplicate to be updated DELETE FROM EmailListCopy WHERE autoid='".$autoid."'</p>";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //The duplicate autoid is lower then the one used to query either an entry we already but is still in the arrays, or something else. 
                        //This is to be skipped.
                        echo "<p>Duplicate not to be updated</p>";
                    }

                }
                $result="Merged ".$duplicatesFound." rows.";
            }
            mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
        }
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($duplicatestmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($link);
}
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: After making a few syntax error fixes I was able to get the script to run but it deleted all of the records out of the 23,000 except for 7 of them.

After thinking about it more I made an error in my initial post.  Some of the record my have only an email or a phone and some may not have either.

The script should find if either the phone1 or the email are the same and if so merge.  If both are blank then leave it alone.

Comment: @ToddWelch I added a few lines under `echo "<p>Found Duplicate</p>";` that should check if both the email and phone1 fields are empty and if so then skip it. Be sure to complete the else `}` at under the SQL delete command. Is the code working as expected with the changes?

Comment: You know you can use COUNT in SQL ? Thus removing almost all of that script ?

Comment: @Dave That sounds great. I'm not a very knowledgeable SQL person, so I as per the OP request (wanting a SQL or PHP answer) I let the SQL people have a whack at it first. Then when the OP contacted me for a PHP solution I did my best to answer it the only way that I knew how, for my current knowledge level. What could COUNT in SQL help eliminate?